# Linker cannot find library file with explicit path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

In my makefile, I have specified a library dependency as follows:

```
LDFLAGS := -l/home/karnivaurus/OpenCV-3.0.0/build/lib/libopencv_core.so

all: $(DYNAMIC_NAME)

$(DYNAMIC_NAME): $(OBJS) | $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)
    @ echo LD -o $@
    $(Q)$(CXX) -shared -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LINKFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(DYNAMIC_FLAGS)
```

Now, if I run `make all`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/OpenCV-3.0.0-RC1/build/lib/libopencv_core.so
```

However, in the directory `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/OpenCV-3.0.0-RC1/build/lib`, there is definitely a file called `libopencv_core.so`. I have checked the spelling many times!

Are there any reasons why the linker cannot find this file, even though I have explicitly specified its exact location and passed that to the linker?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you try it on the command line, without using Make?

Answer (score 4):

Either use `-L` for the library path and `-lopencv_core`:

```
LDFLAGS := -L /home/karnivaurus/OpenCV-3.0.0/build/lib/ -lopencv_core
```

or just include the full path to the `.so` file without `-l`.

```
LDFLAGS := /home/karnivaurus/OpenCV-3.0.0/build/lib/libopencv_core.so
```